# MySQL: return values even if WHERE is null

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like so:

```
| article_id | parent_article_id | title         |
|------------|-------------------|---------------|
|         90 |              NULL | First article |
|         91 |                90 | part 2        |
|         92 |                90 | part 3        |
|         93 |                90 | part 4        |
|         94 |              NULL | 2f3           |
|         95 |              NULL | reer          |
```

In a PHP script, I have a `select` drop down box and I want to populate the select control with articles where the `parent_article_id` is null (I want all the parents) excluding the `article_id` im processing.

So, if I'm processing `article_id` 90, I want to return all the available parents, that is  `article_id`: 94, 95 (im excluding the `article_id` im processing: 90)...

If I'm processing `article_id` 91, I want to return: 90, 94, 95...

If I'm processing `article_id` 95, I want to return: 90, 94...

I was able to create the query that works ok:

```
SELECT
    a.article_id,
    a.parent_article_id,
    a.title
FROM
    article a
WHERE
    a.article_id != ? AND a.parent_article_id IS NULL
ORDER BY
    a.article_id

....

$stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $articleid);
$stmt->execute();
```

The problem is when I'm creating a new article and therefore the `article_id` I'm processing is null (doesn't not exist yet)... The query returns nothing, which is logical. I want to return all `parent_article_id` that are null even if the `article_id` doesn't not exist yet?

Is this feasible with one query?

Comment: you should check on http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/  for more information, as you get more query it is vital to understand the concept

Comment: Since `null` is not going to be the ultimate value of `article_id` when the new article is ultimately created, why not use a value of -1 rather than `null` as the temporizing value? I assume -1 will never be a valid existing `article_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the null-safe equality operator `<=>`:

```
SELECT
    a.article_id,
    a.parent_article_id,
    a.title
FROM
    article a
WHERE
    NOT a.article_id <=> ? AND a.parent_article_id IS NULL
ORDER BY
    a.article_id
```

and set `$articleid` to `null`.